# Filling up an array randomly

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, random, data-structures

I'm looking to build a data structure where an array is filled at a random empty position by calling add(). Once a position is filled it cannot be overwritten by another add(). Calling remove(i) frees the position at A[i]. Calls to add() and remove() can be intermixed.

My first thought was to randomly generate a numbers between 0 and n-1 each time add() is called. If it is empty, fill it; if it is full, do a sequential search until an empty one is found. This however has two problems: 1) if the array is mostly full it will take close to O(n) time 2) the random selection will not be uniform.

My second thought was to use a shuffle on the number 1 to n-1 and add in this order, however this doesn't support remove().

Is there a way to implement this guaranteeing constant performance for add() and remove()?

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the array to be filled `work_array[]`. Use two auxiliary arrays, `filled_positions[]` and `empty_positions[]`, containing indices in `work_array[]`, and two counters, `num_filled` and `num_empty`, giving the number of elements in `filled_positions[]` and `empty_positions[]`. Assuming the arrays are indexed from 0, initially `num_filled` is 0, `empty_positions[]` contains 0, 1, 2, ... to *n* - 1, and `num_empty` is *n*.

- To add an element at a random position:

  1. Generate a random number *r* between `0` and `num_empty - 1`, inclusive.
  2. Select the index *i* from `empty_positions[r]`.
  3. If *r* is less than `num_empty` - 1, set `empty_positions[r]` to `empty_positions[num_empty-1]`.
  4. Decrement `num_empty`.
  5. Set `filled_positions[num_filled]` to *i*.
  6. Increment `num_filled`.
  7. Fill the element at `work_array[i]`.
- To remove an element from a random position:

  1. Generate a random number *r* between `0` and `num_filled - 1`, inclusive.
  2. Select the index *i* from `filled_positions[r]`.
  3. If *r* is less than `num_filled - 1`, set `filled_positions[r]` to `filled_positions[num_filled-1]`.
  4. Decrement `num_filled`.
  5. Set `empty_positions[num_empty]` to *i*.
  6. Increment `num_empty`.

You may want to maintain an array of bits, `work_array_map[]`, with `work_array_map[i]` being 1 if `work_array[i]` is filled and 0 otherwise. With `work_array_map[]` you can tell whether an element *i* is filled or not in constant time.

Answer (score -1):

You can keep an separates Linked List for filled and empty array positions. Now generate a random between 0 to ( length of the linked list in consideration  i.e. filled  or empty ) and use this to select a random position from the list. 
Now if you select any element from the filled list then delete the corresponding entry and add it to the empty list.
Surely the traversal of the linked list will take O(lenght of linked list) time, but this eliminates the problem of selecting a filled position while add() or an empty position while remove().